# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840　について

Tags: swift, swift2

```
func sampleGET() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://sample.jp/api/post/[$id]/test", headers: header)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            guard let object = response.result.value else {
                self.showAlert("Cocoaエラー")
                return
            }
    }
}
```

こちらのコードで[$id]に数字を入れたURLから情報をGETしようとすると

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

のCocoaエラーが出てしまいます。
3840はポストの際に渡している引数の不足など、とどこかで見たのですが
今回はGETなのでいまいちわかりません。

原因としては何が考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: 解決いたしました。APIのURLが変わっていたようです。この場合は自己解決として回答して閉めるべきか、質問自体を削除すべきかどちらでしょうか。

Comment: URLが変更になっていたせいでうまくいかなかったのであれば、サーバ側が何らかのエラーレスポンスを返していたはずです。「サーバエラーの時に、記載の処理がNSCocoaErrorDomain, 3840のエラーになることがある」と言う経験を共有していただくことは、大変意味のあることだと思います。時間を取ることでもあるので、後はご自身で判断されれば良いかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sampleGET() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://sample.jp/api/post/[$id]/test", headers: header)
        .responseString { response in
            print(response)
            guard let object = response.result.value else {
                self.showAlert("Cocoaエラー")
                return
            }
    }
}
```

> .responseJSON

---

> .responseString

.responseJSONを.responseStringに書き換えることで下記のような結果が得られ、
サーバへのURLが間違っていることがわかりました。

```
SUCCESS: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>404 Page Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
background-color: #fff;
margin: 40px;
font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
        <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>404 Page Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
        <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```